# Visual Studio load test on cloud- Using multiple agents

Tags: azure-devops, performance-testing, load-testing

How to run load test on cloud with multiple agents using different IP addresses to simulate users across the globe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can select a location at a time, so you need to create multiple tests for each location.

Also, [these features aren’t currently supported](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/get-started-simple-cloud-load-test):

> Network mix property
>
> Agent to Use in test settings - use the core count property instead
>
> SQL Trace properties in run settings
>
> IP switching

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do so. You can create a load test directly in VSTS like [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/get-started-simple-cloud-load-test). You can create a cloud load test in [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-performance-testing) as well.

These are the regions supported in a cloud load test on VSTS

[image]